# Use both historical prices and fundamentals data for predicting portfolio profit?

Tags: monte-carlo, independence, robust

Get highly **accurate probability distribution for the future price of portfolio** using all the data available.

Each stock has two historical data - **daily prices** (scalar time series updated daily) and **fundamentals** (vector time series, updated quarterly).

It's possible to predict probability distribution for future price for individual stock, using both stock price and fundamental data. The problem is **we can't get portfolio distribution this way**. As a sum (convolution) of individual stock distributions - because they are not independent (see last section about joint distributions).

It's also possible to predict portfolio distribution directly from past portfolio prices. We can synthesise past prices for any portfolio, as a sum of past prices of individual stocks in portfolio. And use past portfolio prices to predict the future portfolio price distribution. The problem - **we can't use fundamentals data this way**. As you can't just sum up fundamentals of individual stock same as prices.

**So, we are stuck**. We either can use both historical prices and fundamentals but can't have portfolio distribution. Or we can have portfolio distribution but can't utilise the fundamentals data.

So, how can we utilise all the data and get the portfolio distribution? Or, if it's not possible to get the probability distributions, what kind of other estimates we can get?

Why I need it. There are lots of references to different kinds of portfolios, like "Aggressive Portfolio", "Defensive Portfolio", "Asymmetric Risk Payoff", "Statistical vs Mechanical Hedging" etc. I want to model and see all those different distributions. Or maybe I'm chasing the wrong thing and there are **other ways to see it** without having the distribution?

P.S.

About **joint probabilities**. Summing up non-independent variables requires to know joint probabilities. I want to **avoid dealing with joint probabilities or correlation explicitly by calculating joint probabilities**, it's hard to calculate and estimate the errors, and it changes with time (in normal times correlation could be ~0, in crisis suddenly correlation could jump to ~1 as all stocks go down).

Comment: none of this is going to work, trust me on this

Comment: @Aksakal hmm, it may not be enough to beat the market. But at the very least it should provide more or less reasonable and close to reality distributions for different portfolios, like "stock + gold", "stocks + put options", "safe stocks like mcdonalds etc." vs "risky stocks Facebook etc", no?

Comment: agressive portfolio is supposed to have high expected return and high variance vs defensive with lower return and lower variance. these usually easy are to see by just looking at the composition of portfolio and a few simple assumptions such as expected return/variance/correlation=historical return/variance/correlation

Comment: gold is trivial, it's just another linear asset that hopefully reduced volatility without too much reduction in return. options are nonlinear, they complicate the task. what's purpose of your exercise? it's not to manage your own wealth?

Comment: @Aksakal sorry I was editing my previous comment and accidentally deleted it. The purpose is to calculate the optimal defensive portfolio in the possible downturns. At the very least just defensive, ideally hedge or take some advantage from downturns with put options.

Comment: I do complicated stuff at work, yet for my own portfolio I avoid all of it, and stick to very simple approaches, nothing fancy at all. You're not a quant hedge fund, so don't try acting like one. that would be my advice.

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks for advice, sounds reasonable.

Comment: in the third paragraph u say "because they are not independent (see last section about joint distributions)." What source for last section are you referring to?

Comment: not sure why you're focusing on price distribution of a portfolio when prices are non-stationary. the standard is to look at the return distribution of a portfolio because log returns are stationary representations of price movement. although returns are not i.i.d. either like prices, you would be able to derive an empirical distribution from the portfolio returns time series and will see that it is bell-shaped. this is done without features. In terms of decomposing the portfolio return dist into individual assets' dists, joint probabilities through asset copulae could account for joint probs